# unable place the messages in a queue on AS400 server

Tags: ibm-mq

We are using Websphere MQ version 8.0.on AS400 server one of my application unable to place the messages in queue,and my application is connected through server connection channel and we have checked the channels status my channel is running state only.

We have observed below error from application logs.

error

```
**************************************************************
Job . . :   MQGACT        User . . :   FGLSEC        Number . . . :   198994  



    Job 198994/FGLSEC/MQGACT started on 24/12/18 at 15:18:21 in subsystem     

      QSYSWRK in QSYS. Job entered system on 24/12/18 at 15:18:21.            

    Job 198994/FGLSEC/MQGACT submitted.                                       

 >> CALL PGM(BOHMQMONCL) PARM('GACTREQ                                         

     ')                                                                       

      1300 - STRCMTCTL LCKLVL(*CHG) CMTSCOPE(*JOB)                            

      2200 - CALL PGM(BOHMQMON)          /* The CALL command contains         

      parameters */                                                           

    LSAA QUEQUE :GACTREQ                                                      

    Cannot resolve to object MQOPEN. Type and Subtype X'0201' Authority       

      X'0000'.                                                                 

    Function check. MCH3401 unmonitored by BOHMQMON at statement 1971,        

      instruction X'0056'.                                                    

    Message MCH3401 in BOHMQMON in GACTEXC (C D F G).  

*************************************************************************
```

request to help on this issue.

Comment: Does the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG contain any errors that correspond to the app errors?

Comment: Google search gets this hit: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21518800. Similar error. Might help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like QMQM library is missing in the library list of the job. Make sure you add it before using MQOPEN.